# Gimbal Lock how does it happen?

Tags: graphics, rotation, euler-angles

So I searched on the net and I'm having some problems imagining how the 
gimbal-lock occurs. According to what i saw, it occurs when 2 or more axes align losing a degree of freedom but I can't imagine how will the axes even begin to align?

I mean, when i rotate an object around x-axis (for example) doesn't the y and z axes rotate with the X-axis to remain perpendicular? How are they gonna align? Similarly whenever i rotate around Y or Z axis the other 2 axis rotate together and remain perpendicular don't they?

To get a more clear view what I am having problem imagining, check this video.
At 5:05
https://youtu.be/Mm8tzzfy1Uw?t=305

You'll see when he rotates around the X axis the green and the blue rings remain there where as according to my imagination the green (Y) and blue (Z) axes should have rotated. I don't understand why the rings are still aligned with the world axis?

Comment: Here is simple video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5PDboNJwks. There is one lock, two gimbals could still rotate, but effect is only in one axis rotation

Comment: I have seen it dude, i've seen every video and i know what gimbal lock is. I wanna know how are the axes aligning. Read my question carefully

Comment: I actually managed to understand the problem. Here is another link where I answered it myself and another guy helped me understand it. - 
https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/6233/euler-angles-gimbal-lock-why-non-orthogonal-axes/6251#6251

Answer (score 1):

### Gimbal Lock.

Gimbal lock does not lock an axis but rather it locks the action of the gyro to move freely in all three axis.

The gimbal's three axis, yaw outer ring (axis along up/down), pitch next ring in (axis along left/right), and roll the inner ring (axis along front/back). If you rotate the pitch ring 90 deg in either direction it will align the roll axis with the yaw axis and the gyro will act as if they are one.

The following image will help

[image]

Left. The Gimbal at start, red axis yaw, blue pitch, green roll. Then rotating around pitch 90deg (blue axis),the roll axis (green) is aligned with the yaw axis (red) and you have gimbal lock.

Comment: I know i've seen plenty of videos about it and how is it happening. I'm having problem imagining the aligning part brother. Like i asked in my question when you rotate around 1 axis the other 2 will also rotate. But here the rings don't. What are these rings? There seems to be a difference between the rings and the axes

Comment: @wandering-warrior maybe this will help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock

Comment: I could not understand this too. If you rotate the object in local space, the red axis is also rotated, so there will never be two axes be aligned. If you rotate the object in world space, those three axes even do not change! so it can not be aligned

Comment: @LiuHao To rotate freely in space you need 3 axis each perpendicular to the others. If two axis are aligned you lose a degree of freedom (aka gimbal lock). The red axis (yaw) is fixed to local. If you pitch (around blue) in local space the inner two rings maintain there orientation relative to the world. If you pitch close to 90 deg the yaw axis (red) aligns with the roll axis  (green). The gimbal can no longer roll as there is no axis aligned to the original roll axis.